# Flow is stuck at Apply to each

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow, loop

I have one flow that removes the special characters from string.

I am using **Apply to each** action. Everything was working fine but today I noticed that all of sudden all the instances of the flow are stuck at apply to each action.

[image: r]

No error is thrown as well. The iteration it should run those are also completed but flow does not go to the next action.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you toggle through the 18 iterations?

Answer (score 1):

We've been dealing with the same thing last few days. Eventually contacted MS support and they're telling that it is the licensing issue. The base license allows to execute up to 2000 actions per 24 hours. Once that limit hits, the flow is throttled. Our flow was sitting for 10 hours, which normally takes 15 seconds to finish.

For more information, read license limitations [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)

Comment: hi Matiur, this is a very valuable piece of information. Do you have more details from MS, please? for example, I was wondering if this limitation is lifted if you have a large pool of Power Automate licenses assigned in a tenant. Are we throttled per user? Is this throttling occurs when we trigger the Flow directly or indirectly or both?

Comment: I have a call in a few minutes as to which plan we would upgrade to. Share the info little later

Comment: @MatiurRahman 2000 actions per 24 hours per flow ? or all the flows of that tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Based on MS recommendation, for our case, we need to upgrade to the *Per flow plan* as described
[here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/).
The base O365 license is not going to work us. Also, we need to revise the flow to minimize the action steps in the flow. Since initializing variables is also counted in the total actions in the flow, we need to minimize using them. The MS support engineer also mentioned that some data that workflow needs during execution can be stored in the Common Data Service (CDS), but in the accessing it from there is Not counted towards the total actions.